How to handle my cross-site duplicate?
Today, I asked this question, which seems to be a cross-duplicate of another question.
The question itself is about usage of computer programs, so it does not belong on StackOverflow, but here on SuperUser.
I would like to close my question as a cross-site duplicate, but that seems not to be possible and I don't feel confident asking a 32-voted question with a 40-voted answer to be migrated to another site.
What now?

There isn't a cross-site dupe close reason. You could delete your question, or you could put a comment under it noting the cross-site dupe, and begin the close process.
You might also consider copy/pasting the answer from the SO question, add links and a clear header for attribution, and mark that as the right answer. This would allow future askers on SU to get their Qs closed as regular dupes and not this cross-site awkwardness.


I don't feel confident asking a 32-voted question with a 40-voted answer to be migrated to another site.

It is too late to migrate that question, so that option is off the table. IMHO SE should allow:

cross-site duplicate closing
"crossover questions" between sites
the migration for questions older than 60 days

because cross-site duplicates are too prevalent (e.g. between SU and SO, between ELL and Engish.SE, and between AI/CV/DS/genAI) and result in a lot of wasted human time.

If a question exists in two communities, one of those questions should be deleted, especially if that question is from the same author. There is some benefit if the author isn’t the same since it won’t be a cut and paste copy. I agree the age of a question shouldn’t avoid question migration.
